# Wordpress - Put the_title (); inside an input value of the form

Tags: php, wordpress

As per question you have perhaps been able to guess what my need is, I have several custom post types, without being too crazy I downloaded an excellent plugin for the form called HTML Forms that allows a total customization to us programmers, but now we come to therefore, my goal is to insert the name of the cpt title into the input tag of the form.

Example to make people understand: I have 3 events

to

b

c

within the page that shows these events the input name must take the_title (); of the event you are visiting.

how can i do this?

code:

```
<div class="md-form">
<i class="fas fa-user prefix grey-text"></i>
<input type="text" name="NAME" id="form-name" class="form-control">
<label for="form-name">Your name</label>
</div>

<div class="md-form">
<i class="fas fa-envelope prefix grey-text"></i>
<input type="text" name="EMAIL" id="form-email" class="form-control">
<label for="form-email">Your email</label>
</div>

<div class="md-form">
<i class="fas fa-tag prefix grey-text"></i>
<input type="text"  name="SUBJECT" id="form-Subject" class="form-control">
<label for="form-Subject">Subject</label>
</div>

<div class="md-form">
<i class="fas fa-pencil-alt prefix grey-text"></i>
<textarea id="form-text" name="MESSAGE" class="form-control md-textarea" rows="3"></textarea>
<label for="form-text">Icon Prefix</label>
</div>

<select name="OK" id="test-OK" class="browser-default custom-select custom-select-lg mb-3">
  <option selected>Hai già un Pr di riferimento?</option>
  <option value="xxx@gmail.com">One</option>
  <option value="xxx@gmail.com">Two</option>
</select>

<div class="text-center mt-4">
  <input class="btn btn-light-blue" type="submit" value="Send" />
</div>
```

obviously the answer insert inside the `value = "<?php echo esc_html (get_the_title ()); ?>"` it is obvious that it is not accepted

Comment: So you want to sent the page title in the form so that the recipient will know from which page the message came from?

Comment: @Shado yes i want this

Comment: Use a hidden input for that.

Comment: @Shado this is a basic solution, you think it s this the solution, i open a question on stackoverflow

Comment: @Shado i write in my question : obviously the answer insert inside the value = "<?php echo esc_html (get_the_title ()); ?>" it is obvious that it is not accepted

Comment: You need to get the page id as a variable and then print it in the field.

$pageID = $post_ID;
$page = get_post($pageID);
echo $page->post_title;

Comment: @Shado not work, the shortcode for this form stay into a while cycle, and when im implement php code into editor from this plugin, this not accept it

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add a hidden input field for getting Post Title with form submission like this -

```
<input type="hidden" name="submittedpost" value="{{post.post_title}}" />
```

You can use {{post.ID}} For Id of those post.